# Is there a way to use stabilizer formalism for non-computational basis input states?

Tags: nielsen-and-chuang, clifford-group, stabilizer-state

In Nielsen and Chuang, exercise 10.42 is to use stabilizers to prove the teleportation circuit works as claimed. It has a footnote that it only works given a restricted class of inputs (it doesn't specify what this class is, but presumably anything that can be generated by stabilizer circuits).

Is there any way to use the stabilizer formalism (or an extension of it, or something like it) to prove things like teleportation circuit identities on arbitrary input states?

Comment: The stabilizer formalism works fine for proving that teleportation works. You just show that the X and Z observables of Alice's input qubit end up as the X and Z observables of Bob's output qubit. If it works for those two observables it has to work for everything.

Comment: @CraigGidney Makes sense. Does that same logic extend to entanglement swapping? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_teleportation#Entanglement_swapping, or do you need the full state vector machinery to prove things like that?

Comment: Any circuit that only has stabilizer operations can be handled by the stabilizer formalism. Check if entanglement swapping uses any operations that aren't stabilizer operations.